# SQL Server After Update Trigger Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

i have schema with the following structure;
[image]
In `MPRMain` table, the `Status` can be **1(Aprove), 2(Cancel) and 3(Pending)**. I'm trying to do something like this e.g When someone update the `Status` (in MPRMain) to **2(Cancel)**. I want to Update the `Status` of a `MPRDetail` table to **0 (0 for disable and 1 for enable)**.
So, i have tried to create a trigger for it which looks like this;

```
Alter Trigger Inventory.MprMainUpdate
    ON Inventory.MPRMain
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 

    declare @status as int;
    set @status = (SELECT Status FROM inserted);
    if(@status=2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Inventory.MPRDetail
        SET Status = 0   -- update the status to canceled
        WHERE MPRId = (select MPRId from inserted);
    END

END
```

However, When i try to Set the `Status` of a `MPRMain` to **2 (Cancel)** From **1 (Aprove)**, i don't see any changes in `MPRDetail` table. This should update the `MPRDetail` Status to 0 (0 for disable).

Comment: Your first problem is that you're **wrongfully** assuming that the trigger is called **once per row** - it's not. It's called **once per statement** and your `Inserted` table can (and *will*!) contain multiple rows - so which one do you select with `set @status = (SELECT Status FROM inserted);` - this is **not defined**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take into account that `Inserted` (and `Deleted`) **will** contain multiple rows! You need to handle those with a set-based approach

Comment: @marc_s, any example from you, will be appreciated. I havn't used triggers before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Inserted` can contain multiple rows, you need to write the trigger with a **set-based** approach:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Inventory.MprMainUpdate
    ON Inventory.MPRMain AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
  UPDATE Inventory.MPRDetail
  SET Status = 0
  FROM Inserted i
  WHERE i.Status = 2 AND Inventory.MPRDetail.MPRId = i.MPRId;
END
```

So basically you need to join your actual data table against the `Inserted` pseudo table based on the `MPRId` column, and update all rows in your base table to `Status = 0` where `Inserted.Status = 2`

OK - here I go: assuming your `UPDATE` statement updates four rows, then `Inserted` might look like this in your trigger:

```
MPRId  MprNo  Date  DepartmentId  Status
  1      42     ..    .......        1
  2      43     ..    .......        2
  7      33     ..    .......        7
  9      41     ..    .......        2
```

Now, you `JOIN` this set of data against your `MPRDetail` table and you only pick those rows where the `Status` in `Inserted` is 2 - so you get

```
MPRId  Status  MPRDetail.Status  (other columns of MPRDetail for those values)
  2      2           4           .....................................
  9      2           5           .....................................
```

So in this case, both those rows in `MPRDetail` would have their `Status` updated to 0 inside the trigger - any other rows will not be touched.

Does that make things a bit clearer? If not: where are you stuck, what's still "magic" and thus unclear to you?

Comment: should i remove the first 3 lines, i-e the if condition

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: yes - because those lines are totally not needed when you use my trigger - that code checks the same condition

Comment: sorry, it's working great. Can i have a little more descriptive answer or a link that can help me?

Comment: Everything is clear now. Your time for this is appreciated dear :D

Comment: This is thing is very easy in `MySQL` while hard to do in `SQL Server`.